# Spring security with java config not protecting urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Several days ago I migrated from xml config to Java config and suddenly got that Spring security does not protecting any url, filters not working at all!

I implemented `WebApplicationInitializer` interface to configure Dispatcher servlet, and my config looks this:

```
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.test.project");
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
        new DispatcherServlet(context));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/rest/*");
  }
```

Security config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public AutheProvider authProvider() {
    return new AuthProvider();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
    return new AuthenticationFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public UnauthorizedEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
    return new UnauthorizedEntryPoint();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(
        Arrays.asList(authProvider()));
    providerManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false);
    return providerManager;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
  }
}
```

What I have missed?

`SecurityConfiguration` class is located in `com.test.project` package.

After project starts I can access any URL, there is no `authentication`object in `SecurityContext` and filters are never called, neiter mine, nor Spring Security filters.

Comment: bean of `SecurityConfiguration` class is getting generated?

Comment: @JosAngelGeorge I think yes, because in debugger I see that `configure` method is called and Spring found this class as configuration

Comment: @JosAngelGeorge and all beans, declared in this class are created

Comment: @dur ah, got it. I just needed to extend I more spring security class. Thanks a lot